# Display two div elements in a single line

Tags: asp.net, css

I have two div elements inside a div element as follows.

```
<div style="display: inline;">
  <div style="display: inline; float: left;width:90%;">
     <p style="display: block; float: left;">
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Text") %>&nbsp;                                                        
     </p>
  </div>
  <div id="divImage" runat="server" style="display: inline; float: right; width: 10%;">
     <a href='<%= ImagePath%><%# Eval("Image") %>'>
     <img src="<%= ImagePath%><%# Eval("Image") %>" alt="Text" width="40px" height="40px" /></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to display both the child div elements with (90% and 10% width respectively) when the image path is valid. If an image is not available, I would like to hide the second child div (id:divImage). So the text would cover the entire available space. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use JQuery to do it at client side

http://api.jquery.com/css/

From server side

```
<div runat="server" id="divControl">...</div>
```

Class of the Page:

```
protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divControl;
OnLoad/Other function:

divControl.Style.Add("height", number / anotherNumer);
```